# Integrating Autofac with Microsoft Azure Mobile Services

Tags: c#, azure-mobile-services

I've created a mobile table controller:

```
[MobileAppController]
[Authorize]
public class EventOrganiserMembershipDtoController : TableController<EventOrganiserMembershipDto>
{
    private readonly IModelContext _modelContext;

    public EventOrganiserMembershipDtoController(IModelContext modelContext)
    {
        _modelContext = modelContext;
    }

    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        DomainManager = new EventOrganiserMembershipDomainManager((DbContext)_modelContext, controllerContext.Request);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't accept dependency injection, despite the fact that I've set it up in my project.

According to all the searching I've done, to achieve this task, which should be trivially easy, I need the line `ServiceConfig.Initialize(new ConfigBuilder(options))`. But I have no idea where this mythical `ServiceConfig` class is supposed to live. Is it obsolete? Is there a newer way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `ServiceConfig` call: I presume it's part of the legacy mobile server infrastructure. You just need to pass a container into the scaffolding: add an `IContainer` argument to the boilerplate code

```
    public static void ConfigureMobileApp(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

        new MobileAppConfiguration()
            .UseDefaultConfiguration()
            .ApplyTo(config);

        // Use Entity Framework Code First to create database tables based on your DbContext
        Database.SetInitializer(new MobileServiceInitializer());

        MobileAppSettingsDictionary settings = config.GetMobileAppSettingsProvider().GetMobileAppSettings();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.HostName))
        {
            app.UseAppServiceAuthentication(new AppServiceAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // This middleware is intended to be used locally for debugging. By default, HostName will
                // only have a value when running in an App Service application.
                SigningKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningKey"],
                ValidAudiences = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidAudience"] },
                ValidIssuers = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidIssuer"] },
                TokenHandler = config.GetAppServiceTokenHandler()
            });
        }

        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

and replace

```
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
```

with

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration
{
    DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container)
};
```

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved this issue. You could mark your reply as an acceptable answer which could help other community members who could encounter this similar issue.

Comment: Another 12 hours, and I can do so. That's the rules of Stack Overflow.